# How to dynamically add markers to countries?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jqvmap

Anyone used http://jqvmap.com/ before?

Is there way to dynamically add dots (or some kind of marker) to the map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try to use new version of jVectorMap. It has this feature. Here is an [example](http://jvectormap.com/examples/markers-world/).

Comment: Thanks bjornd, I'm sad to say jqvmap is starting to feel like an abandoned project. I was using it cos I stumbled upon it before the original jVectorMap. I'm Migrating to jVectorMap right away.

Comment: Thanks Cogicero. I haven't commited to jVectorMap repo for a long time too. Though I'm gonna continue to work on the project very soon.

Comment: Hi again Bjornd, can you please point me in the right direction? I created my jvectormap myself but I have no idea why the latlong coordinates are not showing as markers on the map. I suspect maybe my projection data (type and centralMeridian) values are wrong, or else the inset and bbox values, cos my paths are very correct. I created the SVG map myself so I need to know how to get the correct projection centralMeridian etc values to use for the map. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 1):

jqvmap uses svg image for showing map.
You can edit svg image and add dots according to you. Here is a link to svg editor http://svg-edit.googlecode.com/svn/branches/2.5.1/editor/svg-editor.html

Install firebug in FF and following steps

1. Open the link above.(of svg editor)
2. Open http://jqvmap.com/ in another tab.( Or the page where your map is rendered)
3. Inspect the map with firebug. You will find there is a `<svg>` tag which contains all the map data.
4. In the `<svg>` tag there is a `g` tag. In firebug right the `<g>` tag and copy svg code.
5. Come back to first window (svg editor)
6. click the 2nd menu button to view svg source. (or press `U`)
7. replace the `<g>` tag with the code you copied.
8. Apply Changes
9. Now you can place dots where you want. (just explore the tool)

Comment: Im trying to add "markers" dynamically on the map, via js. Not make my own custom map